# "Permission Denied" as root when moving files

Tags: permissions, root, mv

Using `sudo` on the [RPISEC-MBE virtual machine](https://github.com/RPISEC/MBE), I have mounted and copied my files that were on a USB flash drive to an admin folder (that I have access to). Unfortunately, even with `sudo` I can't seem to copy them to the `/levels/lecture` directory. Why is it not letting me copy those files in, even as root?

```
gameadmin@warzone:~$ mkdir /media/usb ; sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/usb
gameadmin@warzone:~$ ls -l /media/usb/rpisec
total 32
drwxr-xr-x  2  root  root  16384  Jun  7  15:41  bombs
drwxr-xr-x  2  root  root  16384  Jun  7  15:41  crackme
gameadmin@warzone:~$ sudo cp -R /media/usb/rpisec/* /home/gameadmin/
gameadmin@warzone:~$ ls -l /home/gameadmin
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2  root  root  4096  Jun  7  15:42  bombs
drwxr-xr-x  2  root  root  4096  Jun  7  15:42  crackme
gameadmin@warzone:~$ ls -l /levels/lecture
total 28
drwxr-xr-x  2  root  root  4096  Jun  21  2015  aslr
drwxr-xr-x  2  root  root  4096  Jun  21  2015  cpp
drwxr-xr-x  2  root  root  4096  Jun  21  2015  format_strings
drwxr-xr-x  2  root  root  4096  Jun  21  2015  heap
drwxr-xr-x  2  root  root  4096  Jun  21  2015  misc
drwxr-xr-x  2  root  root  4096  Jun  21  2015  rop
drwxr-xr-x  2  root  root  4096  Jun  21  2015  shellcode
gameadmin@warzone:~$ sudo mv /home/gameadmin/* /levels/lecture/
mv: cannot move '/home/gameadmin/bombs' to '/levels/lecture/bombs': Permission denied
mv: cannot move '/home/gameadmin/crackme' to '/levels/lecture/crackme': Permission denied
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://github.com/RPISEC/MBE#why-am-i-getting-permission-denied-errors):

> The warzone marks many files as immutable to prevent users from changing them and ruining the game for other players. For example, we don't want the lab2B user to delete its .pass file or /levels files. A few system files, such as /etc/passwd, are also marked immutable.
>
> If you would like to modify or delete these files simply remove the immutable flag: `chattr -i filename`
>
> We recommend that you add the flag back when you are done making your changes: `chattr +i filename`

File immutability is a wonderful thing in many circumstances. If you have the opportunity, learning how to use these can save you a lot of headache later

Comment: How could I have missed that?! Thanks so much!   ( XD )